# How to build an user authentication and login system using only a file but not database?

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android studio and just learnt basic java. I want to build an user authentication system in android studio using only file,not database but don't know how to do that. Please help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make your layout and all the required views. Provide validations to the required views to check if the entered values are correct or not.

For login check this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_login_screen.htm

Answer (score 0):

Providing Hypothetical Design.

Login class

```
public class Login {

    private String mUsername;
    private String mPassword;

    Login(String username,String password){
        mUsername = username;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    public String getmPassword() {
        return mPassword;
    }

    public String getmUsername() {
        return mUsername;
    }

    public void setmPassword(String mPassword) {
        this.mPassword = mPassword;
    }

    public void setmUsername(String mUsername) {
        this.mUsername = mUsername;
    }


}
```

Create UI for username and password in xml.
Create Login object.You can learn from official https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-user-input--ud836 course

To cache in file.
Use `File` api and read write in file while validating login.

***Note: But this is very very basic thing and this is not recommendable for authantication module as this is not secure thing.***

You must use database and ContenProvider for login module.

Thanks

Happy Coding.